# Using SQL Profiler on an Azure Dedicated SQL Pool using Azure Data Studio

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, sql-server-profiler, azure-data-studio

I am attempting to monitor direct query from power bi on a synapse dedicated sql pool.  From SSMS I was unable to log into profiler (it offered only windows and sql authentication, i am using AAD with MFA)

I then read that I need to use Azure Data Studio and to install the SQL Profiler Extension.  I successfully added it.

When trying to connect to the database with SQL profiler using alt + P, I am connecting to a specific db, it is not using the default setting I get this error;

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.

From the help / toggle / toggle developer tools in azure data studio i see this in the error log

[From Azure Data Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dmb62.png)

I found this old issue https://github.com/microsoft/azuredatastudio/issues/6353

but running the solution in the github reference that worked for some didn't work for me, plus this was back in 2019.

Wondering if anyone had a clue.. Not sure what else I am missing?

I updated Azure Data Studio to the latest version
I installed the extension Admin Pack for SQL Server + SQL Server Profiler
I played with the connection settings with all variations of encrypt + trust server certificate did not have any affect.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to dedicated SQL pool to SSMS via AAD with MFA authentication in latest version of SSMS.

Try to connect in SSMS using AAD- Universal with MFA authentication by entering username:

[image]

Next go to options select the database by browsing you will get sign in page enter the password.

[image]

you will get database list as below:

[image]

select it and click connect, it will connect successfully.,

[image]

If you want to connect in azure data studio go to connections click new connection and fill the required fields and click on connect

[image]

It will connect successfully:

[image]